# How to integrate Firefox Sync?

Tags: firefox, synchronization, firefox-addon

Firefox 4 comes soon (ok, next year ;)) and there is a Firefox plugin to sync your bookmarks etc. with Firefox 3.whatever .

I would like to know if anyone has a comprehensive, up-to-date tutorial to integrate Firefox Sync into your own plugin? Or any idea regarding this?

I mainly followed [this official "tutorial"](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Weave/ClientAPI) and also [this blog post](http://adblockplus.org/blog/adding-weave-support-to-an-extension), but the information seems to be slightly outdated.
For example, the object is not called `Weave` anymore but `Engines` and the `weave.engines.` preference became `services.sync.engines.`. I played a little with all the mentioned options, but it does not seems to work (and my plugin does not show up in list where you can select what to sync).

I assume that the `Tracker` and `Store` classes are fine, the main problem is to *register* the engine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ClientAPI](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Weave/ClientAPI) tutorial you mention is definitely the way to go. I updated it recently so if something's not working, please let us know so I can fix it in the docs. Wladimir's blogpost is definitely quite old and contains some outdated information. We will also make changes to some parts of the API in the upcoming beta releases, so be prepared for some flux...

The `Weave` namespace is still the canonical way to access Sync related APIs from UI code. It exposes components such as `Weave.Service` and `Weave.Engines`. You can import it via `Components.utils.import("resource://services-sync/main.js")`. If you want to implement your own engine, you'll have to import the actual underlying modules, though (all listed in the ClientAPI tutorial). The tutorial also describes how to register your custom engine implementation. Once it's registered, it won't automatically show up in the preferences UI, though. I suggest building your own UI that flips the `services.sync.engine.YOURENGINE` pref in your add-on's preferences.

Out of curiosity, what kind of data are you trying to sync?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I will give it another try. I was just confused by the different information given. Do I still have to add my engine to `services.sync.registerEngines` (like it is written at the end)? I created the FloatNotes plugin, which lets you create kinda sticky notes on websites. I want to sync these notes, so it is basically just text entered by users and some meta data position etc. Maybe this is not the right place to ask, but I was wondering whether the sync process runs in a background thread or something like that? Because my data is stored in a SQLite database

Comment: and for some methods (like `getAllIDs()`) I have to return every record and I can't make an asynchronous call, as the method does not accept a callback. So I was wondering if it has any serious performance impact? Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, sticking your engine into the Weave object and adding the name to services.sync.registerEngines is definitely a good way to get your engine registered.

Comment: Yes unfortunately all of Sync's APIs are synchronous. This is something we'd like to fix eventually, but it's unlikely it'll happen for Firefox 4. We're using the Sync.js tool internally to make some asynchronous processes look synchronous. You just have to import resource://services-sync/ext/Sync.js and then wrap a function that takes a callback with Sync(func). That returns a synchronous looking function.

Comment: Ok, I got it working, thank you for your help! (especially for the `Sync` tool). Btw. I think it is worth mentioning in the tutorial how and when records should be marked as deleted (it was not too difficult to figure it out, but it is not bad to mention it). The other point was that I didn't know *when* to attach the engine etc. I noticed that when I do it in the `load` event handler, it is sometimes to late...